# Work on an existing Java EE application eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, import

I'm trying to import an existing application in Eclipse, but I don't really understand how it works. The project is already compiled and I have to modify some jsp files and to create some new servlets. Is it possible? And how does it work? The structure looks like this (type of files inside the folders between brackets) :

[image]

I have created a new dynamic web project and I have imported all of it into the WebContent folder but Eclipse can't build it, so I guess I'm wrong..

EDIT: Import existing project does not work:

[image]

Comment: It's wise to start with a Hello World and work through some basic tutorials first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import existing projects(any type) from below location in Eclipse

File > Import > Existing Project into Workspace.

However, if you want to  to import a Web Project which is written using other IDE than Eclipse and if it is pure web project then use WAR import, because it is a complete way to import any kind of web project.

File > Import > Web > War file

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I can't, I edit my question with a picture..

Comment: Did you try the war file import?

Comment: I need to create a war ^^ I'm looking how I can do (I'm not comfortable with java yet)

Comment: You can also decompile your project using [Java Decompiler plugin](http://jd.benow.ca/). This plugin can help you to decompile your project and then import your project

Comment: I'm doing the import, I think it will be long. I'll tell you if it works. Thank you!

Comment: It works (there are a lot of errors and I had "GC overhead limit exceeded" error during the build but I solve it). Thank you very much Mitsu. Sorry to can't add points to your answer but I loss reputation with this question ^^ I'll do it later.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help :)